# SSRS - different values in exports

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel

is it possible to export other values to Excel than displayed in the report?

For Example: Report Displays Hours (5) -> Export shows Minutes (300)

thank you in advance

Comment: any reason why you can't add that change in the script?

Comment: I dont know how. I have a Value in the DB that is shown in the Tablix. I set the Textfield properties (Formatting-options) to Hours for the Report itself. But i need Minutes in Excel.

Comment: One way of doing it is to create and excel-friendly version of the report and add a link to it in the original that automatically exports to excel (by passing the export parameters directly in the URL) That way you can customise the layout completely, and the user doesn't notice any extra reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for SSRS 2012 and Excel 2016. Use an expression in the text box that you want to change.

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML","Minute Value","Hour Value")
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to do it

Comment: Glad I could help.